# simulate ajax call using C#

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax, httpwebrequest

I am making an ajax call to a local resource like this

```
$.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost:10001',
                    dataType: "text",
                    data: { a: 'aVal',b: 'bVal',message: 'message' },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#test").append(data);
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown) {
                        alert('error '+textStatus+" "+errorThrown);
                    }
                });
```

Now i just want to simulate the call from C#.
I am able to make a raw call using this code

```
 WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:10001");
 request.ContentType = "text";
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

i dont know how to send the data along.If there is a better way, kindly suggest

---

**Also,** I want this to have the exact structure and appearance because i am handling the request at the node js server like this

```
var url=require('url');
var url_parts=url.parse(request.url,true);
var data=url_parts.query;
```

Thanks

Comment: [Take a look at this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13228046/656243) Pretty sure it'll have all of the code you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is a get request you can pass parameters in query string of url:

```
 string aVal="aVal";
 string bVal="bVal";
 string message="message";
 string Url ="http://localhost:10001?a="+aVal+"&b="+bVal+"&message="+message;
 WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
```

For details on [How to make get and post Request in C# see this article](http://codesamplez.com/programming/http-request-c-sharp)

Comment: had it been a post request??

Comment: @ankur what you mean?

Comment: if i want to make a POST and not a GET